# Wordpress WPforms customization

Tags: plugins, php, forms, sql

Firstly I would like to apologize because my question may be a little bit nooby. For the educational purposes I am building app to keep several different records in DB and then make custom query from it.

Because of easy use I make the decision to use Wordpress and there put all the pages and different forms for inputting data.

For the input I am using WPforms plugin. But I soon saw that inputs are stored in custom WPforms database and there is no chance to change the target DB.

I am good in HTML and CSS but unfortunately I cannot say this for php and SQL. But I am a fast learner.

My idea is to make small add on for WPform which will allow to choose for each form in which table and field in which column put posted data. I would like for little help here because I don't know where to start. In thanks for all the help once the plugin is complete I would also share it with you.

Thanks in advance.